# Bootstrap grid layout how to? 2 columns of 3 (desktop) --> 3 columns of 2 (tablet)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make it so that it forms 3 columns of 2 on tablet and 2 columns on 3 on desktop. I feel I am doing it properly however it still only shows 3 and then 3.... not 2 then 2 then 2 on tablet. Any idea?

```
    <div class="fluid-container" id="capabilities">
            <h2 class="center">
                SKILLS AND SERVICES
            </h2>

            <div class="row services">

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 padding-icon">
                    <img src="images/1.jpg">
                    <h4>

                    </h4>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 padding-icon">
                    <img src="images/2.jpg">
                    <h4>

                    </h4>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 padding-icon">
                    <img src="images/3.jpg">
                    <h4>

                    </h4>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 padding-icon">
                    <img src="images/4.jpg">
                    <h4>

                    </h4>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 padding-icon">
                    <img src="images/5.jpg">
                    <h4>

                    </h4>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 padding-icon">
                    <img src="images/6.jpg">
                    <h4>

                    </h4>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: a row has a total size `12` and you are giving 6 columns of size 6 in a single row (for sm and md). It's not correct make the size distribution right.

Comment: Yes but according to a related post, it doesn't matter... if you go beyond 12 bootstrap should understand and adapt.

Answer (score 1):

You have somewhat mixed up the classes in Bootstrap's scaffolding system. The number in a class like `.col-lg-4` represents how many columns the element takes up. Given that we know Bootstrap uses a 12-column grid system, we just need to calculate how wide (in columns) each element needs to be to achieve the desired layout:

- For tablet (sm), you want 3 columns per row. 12/3 = 4, so each element should have `.col-sm-4`.
- For desktop (md), you want 2 columns per row. 12/2 = 6, so each element should have `.col-md-6`. (You got this one correct.)
- There's no need for a `.col-lg-*` class, because above the md breakpoint you're likely looking at a desktop monitor.

Therefore, each element should have the classes `.col-sm-4 .col-md-6`, like in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/eMvzKwiuxj). Hope this helps! Sometimes just sitting down and working through the math can be really helpful.

(If you also want the tablet layout to appear on phone-width devices, then you should use `.col-xs-4` instead of `.col-sm-4`.)

Comment: Actually it is the other way around, I want 3 columns per row on desktop and 2 columns per row on desktop. I think my math is correct but when it displays it still appears unmatched.. they don't come together.

Comment: @BenjaminLawson Aaah, okay. Guess your wording is a little misleading then, since "3 columns of 2 on tablet" is 3 columns per row on tablet. You should probably double-check your wording in your question, maybe swap instances of that to "3 rows of 2" or "2 columns of 3", and the same for desktop. Can you include a screenshot of what you're seeing? Is this occurring with just base Bootstrap styles? (ie. Any custom CSS written?)